# Date and time picker on iOS 14.4

Tags: ios, swift, ios14.5

I added Date picker view as keyboard controller on the UItextfiewld
still now it was working properly but in latest version of iOS 14.4 getting date picker view very small. here I am attaching the screenshot for it

[image]

How we can solve this in iOS 14.4 ?

Comment: What difference does the iOS version make when you use the date picker with the simulator?

Comment: you may need to set the new date picker style if you are looking for the classical date picker as wheel, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepickerstyle

Answer (score 0):

**Try to add this code programatically**

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
   self.datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set preferdPickerStyle to your datepicker

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
  self.datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
} else {
  // fallback to older version 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 14.4 or above iOS change the design for the date picker view so in that case if you want to continue showing older design you have to do code as per the iOS version. and for that here is the version base condition code

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
  self.datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```

here `self.datepicker` is your datePicker object